# Why opencv distort the image by undistort()?

Tags: python, opencv, matrix, computer-vision

I am following the [OpenCV Camera Calibration tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html), I have used about 100 images for the calibration. After getting camera matrix and distance matrix, I use them to undistort other set of images. What I realized is the undistorted image is highly distorted on both sides.

One of the example imgs for camera matrix:
[image]

**Using the camera matrix to undistort my experimental img gave me very unreasonable results.**

**Original image:**
[image]

**After applying undistor():**
[image]

**Clearly, the undistortion process only paid attention to the center of the image. How can I make it undistort the image properly?**

Thank you very much!

**UPDATE:
Using images to cover the Filed of View as much as possible helps. Here is the new result of the same imag**e:
[image]

I have one more question: How to know if the calibration returns satisfying calibration results? RMS is a parameter. However, it is not very robust.

Comment: If the calibration process wasn't done right, it might give that result.  It's hard to say what you did wrong, but if the first image is an indication, I would say you need to make the board take most of the frame (as much as possible) and vary the angles you hold the board in all directions.

Comment: try to cover the whole image with the calibration pattern, maybe using multiple images, each covering some part of the visual field.

Comment: @Micka. Thank you very much!. I tried again by using images that allow the chessboard to cover the field of view as much as possible. I got better results, although the RMS is larger than 1 (1.59).

Comment: @Photon, Thank you very much! Covering all of the angles help. Is there any way to measure the calibration performance, except for the RMS returned by  'cv2.calibrateCamera()'?

Comment: You might want to invest into some lights, that image is quite underexposed.

Comment: @DanMašk. Thank you very much! I did try sample images under brighter condition. In the same time, I took suggestion from Photon and Micka by making images to cover all of the field of view of the camera. The results are much better, and reasonable.